# Unable to Clone Gerrit Repository

Tags: git, gerrit, git-bash

I am trying to connect to gerrit hosted on my VPS. I am using Git Bash for windows. I have generated SSH keys using ssh-keygen in GitBash and added key on gerrit server as well.
when i run `ssh -p 29418 <username>@<gerrit-server>` i will see below welcome message

```
  ****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

  Hi Full Name, you have successfully connected over SSH.

  Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
  To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

  git clone ssh://username@<gerrit-server>:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git
```

but when i clone the repository by running following command

```
git clone ssh://<username>@<gerrit-server>:29418/project-name.git
```

i see the following error in my Git Bash terminal

```
Cloning into 'project-name'...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am not able to understand what's going on and how to successfully clone my projects in my machine. Can anyone please help me in this matter?

**Update-1:**
I am still not able to figure out what the problem is but i just want to share some weird thing which is happening right now. I created another SSH key and this time i added a passphrase for the SSH key. I added that key on the SSH server as well. Normally when there is a passphrase attached to the key the Git Bash terminal should asks for the passphrase to unlock the private key. 
Now what's happening right now is if i ssh gerrit server by running command 
`ssh -p 29418 <username>@<gerrit-server>` it asks me to unlock passphrase that means its using the correct ssh key and it displays the Gerrit welcome message 
 *The problem is that it don't ask for the passphrase when i run the git clone command listed above, that means that its using some other SSH key that's why i get `SSH_exchange_identification` error from Gerrit. Is there any other step i need to perform before cloning? Do i have to do any Git Setting to successfully clone Git Repository?*

Comment: Is username the user configured as Username on the Profile tab of the Settings screen? (as mentioned in https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/user-upload.html#test_ssh)

Comment: Yes username is configured that's why the i am able to see the welcome message after running ssh -p 29418 <username>@<gerrit-server>

Comment: I menat, Username on the Profile tab of the Settings screen of the Gerrit web interface, not ssh.

Comment: Yes i have configured the username and i am using that username

Comment: Try using `ssh -p 29418 <username>@<gerrit-server> gerrit ls-projects` and check if your project is there. If not then you need to change your access rights.

Comment: I have tried this and the list returned has my project in it. I have also edited the access rights for it

Comment: i have checked and my projects are showing up fine there

Comment: are you copying ssh clone link from the gerrit UI?

Comment: yes i am copying the exact URL and its still raising ssh_exchange_identification error

Comment: Please check the Update-1 I think its causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Configure your git settings -> <kbd>config</kbd>

add `user.name` and `email` (which is used in your gerrit settings)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem, Its not working for latest versions of Git.

It worked fine for me for git version - 2.29.3.

If you want to identify which ssh key is being used then try adding this a file inside .ssh folder named as **config** with below content. This will help you identify which ssh-key is being used -

```
# Gerrit 
Host gerrit.*.com
   host gerrit.*.com
   user user_name
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
when I run `ssh -p 29418 <username>@<gerrit-server> gerrit ls-projects`,
I will see the list of projects, but when i clone the repository, i see the same error.
I didn't find the reason, but I finally can clone the repository from gerrit.
The path is: gerrit->setting->HTTP Credentials-> generate new password -> copy it.
then go to your local shell, git clone repository using http, not using ssh.
when ask you passward, paste the string just copied on gerrit.
hope i can help some guys!